# Windows store application re-install

Tags: windows

I've tried to reinstall windows store app, with this command

```
Get-AppXPackage *WindowsStore* -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

But I got these error message ->

```
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF0, Package could not be opened.
error 0x80070003: Opening file from location: AppxBundleManifest.xml failed with error: The system cannot find the path specified.
.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 20374eb9-49c4-000f-aae6-3720c449d701 in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 20374eb9-49c4-000f-aae6-3720c449d701
At line:1 char:53
+ ...  | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.I ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (C:\Program File...ppXManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

Then I tried to  get more information with this command 

 

    Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 20374eb9-49c4-000f-aae6-3720c449d701

But is totally meanningless ->>

Time                      ID           Message
----                      --           -------
16/05/2021 00:49:48       603          Started deployment Register operation on a package with main parameter AppXManifest.xml and Options 0 and 0. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
                                       deployment issues.
16/05/2021 00:49:48       819          The following packages will be installed: 1527c705-839a-4832-9118-54d4Bd6a0c89_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       c5e2524a-ea46-4f67-841f-6a9465d9d515_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy E2A4F912-2574-4A75-9BB0-0D023378592B_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       F46D4000-FD22-4DB4-AC8E-4E1DDDE828FE_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Microsoft.AccountsControl_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.AsyncTextService_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_8wekyb3d8bbwe
                                       Microsoft.BioEnrollment_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.CredDialogHost_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Microsoft.ECApp_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_8wekyb3d8bbwe Microsoft.LockApp_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_10.0.19041.964_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_44.19041.964.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
                                       Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.Windows.AppRep.ChxApp_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Microsoft.Windows.AssignedAccessLockApp_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.Windows.CallingShellApp_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Microsoft.Windows.CapturePicker_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.Windows.NarratorQuickStart_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_8wekyb3d8bbwe
                                       Microsoft.Windows.OOBENetworkCaptivePortal_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.Windows.OOBENetworkConnectionFlow_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Microsoft.Windows.ParentalControls_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.Windows.PeopleExperienceHost_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Microsoft.Windows.PinningConfirmationDialog_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.Windows.Search_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_10.0.19041.964_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.Windows.SecureAssessmentBrowser_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Microsoft.Windows.XGpuEjectDialog_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_120.2212.2020.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy MicrosoftWindows.UndockedDevKit_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       NcsiUwpApp_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_8wekyb3d8bbwe Windows.CBSPreview_10.0.19041.964_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy windows.immersivecontrolpanel_10.0.2.1000_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
                                       Windows.PrintDialog_6.2.1.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy . The following packages will be removed: NULL


16/05/2021 00:49:48       405          error 0x80070003: Opening file from location: AppxBundleManifest.xml failed with error: The system cannot find the path specified.
                                       .
16/05/2021 00:49:48       402          error 0x80070003: Reading manifest from location: AppxBundleManifest.xml failed with error: The system cannot find the path specified.
                                       .
16/05/2021 00:49:48       404          AppX Deployment operation failed for package Microsoft.WindowsStore_11909.1001.713.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe with error 0x80073CF0. The specific error text for this failure is: error
                                       0x80070003: Opening file from location: AppxBundleManifest.xml failed with error: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The system cannot find the path specified. : which path ???

I took ownership of the Windowapp folder and changed rights.

Comment: Try the install command this way:   Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}   See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I did already this command, but I have tons of error messages (red strings).

Add-AppxPackage : Cannot find path 'C:\AppXManifest.xml' because it does not exist.

This link is interesting but I cannot install the package, it say this is for XBOX device when unpacking it ...

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-windows-store-windows-10-uninstall-with-powershell/

Edit -> the is THE file to grab

Microsoft.WindowsStore_12104.1001.113.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe.appxbundle

and reinstallation went FINE - SOLVED